# Getting error while importing mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am importing the follwoing mysql example

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila-installation.html

when i try to import then i get this error on centos

`SOURCE sakila-schema.sql;`

`ERROR 1548 (HY000) at line 446: Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted`

The seems to get imported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*you should try this one and refer this [**link1**](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62379) and [**link2**](http://webcheatsheet.com/sql/Fix_Cannot_load_from_mysql.proc._The_table_is_probably_corrupted.php)*

```
mysql_upgrade -u root -p
```

---

```
mysql_upgrade.exe -uroot -p --force
```